# Spring config file location relatively to the running program

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Spring Boot you can set the config file location using the `spring.config.location` property.

How can I set the config file location to the folder where the application file is?

Imagine this:

- `/abc/application.yml`
- `/abc/program.jar`

And I'm currently here: `/home/user/`

"." takes the current working directory. But how to reference the application directory?

Comment: Did you try with absolute full path ?

Comment: are you looking for relative path?

Comment: Maybe it gets clearer with an alternative: When developing a simple Windows application using Microsoft Visual Studio and C# you can by default use a configruation file called <applicationname>.exe.config and this file can be placed right by the application exe file. I don't have to start the application with a special argument telling where to find this config file. And I want do the same using Java and Spring. How to make the Java application watch out for a config file in the same directory?